# In aws will snapshots be cheaper than AMIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cost-management

I know you can create AMIs from a snapshot.
Snapshots are cheaper to store than AMIs
and that AMIs of a stopped instance are cheaper to store than an AMI of a running instance.

Will an AMI of a stopped instance stored in EBS and
a snapshot of that AMI is stored in s3 be cheaper?

I don't however know if there's a charge to create an AMI from a snapshot then destroy it after creating an instance from it?

I can't see this information in billing management?

Also if there's any other considerations you can think that would add costs of such as if I wanted to use it for more than just retaining older backups how to create an instance from a snapshot in terraform as that's what I'm using without needing to create an AMI.

Note: I'd like to give this question a discussion tag but can't see one.
I don't know if/how I can do that on stack exchange?